# Return the options which Bootstrap Datepicker is working with

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Let's say that the Bootstrap datepicker was initialized like this.

```
$('#myDate').datepicker({
    orientation: "left",
    autoclose: true,
    forceParse: false,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy.',
    startDate: '30.11.2019.',
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Is it possible to do something along the lines of this (the following code will not work, but it illustrates what I want to do)?

```
var start = $('#myDate').datepicker('startDate');
console.log(start);
outputs 30.11.2019.
```

If it is possible, how can I do this? I need this for debugging purposes - `startDate` is not working, and I'm unsure if anything else is overwriting it / disabling it.

Comment: Leaving this for those who might run into the same issue. I've discovered that the `date-picker` class (inputs had it) was responsible for `startDate` not working. After removing it from both of the date inputs, `startDate` started working.